# How to get center point of cell

Tags: swift

I want to show the `AddView` in my Xib File whenever I click on the cell which indexPath.row == 0:

[image]

But I don't want it appear like this, I want it to show from the center of the cell which `indexPath.row == 0` (The + image), and start with the width and height = 1, then it animate to be bigger and bigger, and come into the center of the view.

How to do that.

Here is my current code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 && addViewIsShowed == false {
            addViewIsShowed = true
            collectionView.alpha = 0.5
            addView.delegate = self
            addView.center = (collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.contentView.center)!
            addView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            addView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatYellowColor()
            view.insertSubview(addView, aboveSubview: collectionView)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.2, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.addView.bounds.size.width = 300
                self.addView.bounds.size.height = 400
                self.addView.center = self.view.center
                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

After doing base on @Zell B guide.

Code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 && addViewIsShowed == false {
            addViewIsShowed = true
            collectionView.alpha = 0.5
            addView.delegate = self
            addView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            let cellContentView = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.contentView
            let rect = cellContentView!.convertRect(cellContentView!.frame, toView: self.view)
            addView.center = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width / 2, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height / 2)
            addView.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatYellowColor()
            view.insertSubview(addView, aboveSubview: collectionView)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.2, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.addView.bounds.size.width = 120
                self.addView.bounds.size.height = 160
                self.addView.center = self.view.center
                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

The AddView still not change the size:

[image]

**Update 2**

After adding `addView.clipsToBounds = true` above of animation. It works.

[image]

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By getting center point of cell directly from its content view you will get its center relative to cell superview, which in your case is collection view. Since `UICollectionView` is subclass of `UIScrollView` things will get complicated because of scrollView's contentView and you will hardly get the desired point. To simplify this problem you can easily convert cell's frame relative to view controller's view or relative to application window and then set the converted point to your added view.

```
let cellContentView = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.contentView
let rect = cellContentView!.convertRect(cellContentView!.frame, toView: self.view) // pass toView nil if you want to convert rect relative to window
addView.center = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width / 2, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height / 2)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. But how about the size, it didn't change. I want it to be bigger and bigger. For example the width from 1 to 300

Comment: @khuong291 Size change should work with your current animation block

Comment: Please check again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @khuong291 As I can clearly see the background view with yellow background color is becoming bigger while animation is running (meaning that animation block is working). If the view with pine is subview of that view and you want it to animate too simply add this line of code `addView.clipsToBounds = true` before starting animation

Comment: It worked. Thanks again. I will adjust the subViews of AddView.