# UITableView: reloadRows(at:) takes two hits for table to be updated and scroll every time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, reloaddata

I have a table view (controller: *MetricsViewController*) which gets updated from a CoreData database. I have used prototype cells (*MetricsViewCell*) which I have customized for my needs. It contains a segmented control, a UIView (metricsChart, which is used to display a chart - animatedCircle), and some UILabels.

**MetricsViewCell**:

```
class MetricsViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var delegate: SelectSegmentedControl?
    var animatedCircle: AnimatedCircle?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var percentageCorrect: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalPlay: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var metricsChart: UIView! {
        didSet {
            animatedCircle = AnimatedCircle(frame: metricsChart.bounds)
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var recommendationLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var objectType: UISegmentedControl!
    
    @IBAction func displayObjectType(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        delegate?.tapped(cell: self)
        
    }
}

protocol SelectSegmentedControl {
    func tapped(cell: MetricsViewCell)
}
```

**MetricsViewController**:

```
class MetricsViewController: FetchedResultsTableViewController, SelectSegmentedControl {

func tapped(cell: MetricsViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}

var container: NSPersistentContainer? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer { didSet { updateUI() } }

private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Object>?

private func updateUI() {
    if let context = container?.viewContext {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Object> = Object.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Object>(
            fetchRequest: request,
            managedObjectContext: context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "game.gameIndex",
            cacheName: nil)
        try? fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Object Cell", for: indexPath)
    if let object = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) {
        
        if let objectCell = cell as? MetricsViewCell {
            objectCell.delegate = self
            
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Object> = Object.fetchRequest()
            ...
            ...

            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

When a user selects one of the segments in a certain section's segmented control, MetricsViewController should reload the data in that particular row. (There are two sections with one row each). Hence, I've defined a protocol in MetricsViewCell to inform inform my controller on user action.

Data is being updated using `FetchedResultsTableViewController` - which basically acts as a delegate between CoreData and TableView. Everything is fine with that, meaning I am getting the correct data into my TableView.

There are two issues:

1. I have to tap segmented control's segment twice to reload the data in the row where segmented control was tapped.
2. The table scrolls back up and then down every time a segment from segmented control is selected.

Help would be very much appreciated. I've depended on this community for a lot of issues I've faced during the development and am thankful already :)

For example, in Animal Recognition section, I have to hit "Intermediate" two times for its row to be reloaded (If you look closely, the first time I hit Intermediate, it gets selected for a fraction of second, then it goes back to "Basic" or whatever segment was selected first. Second time when I hit intermediate, it goes to Intermediate). Plus, the table scroll up and down, which I don't want.

[image]

**Edit**: Added more context around my usage of CoreData and persistent container.

Comment: 2. To avoid scrolling - Try Reload rows without animation. Presently you are specifying automatic animation.

Comment: I. How do you determine which segment control is tapped on ?. Each cell has has its own segment control

Comment: Doesn't work - with .none animation unfortunately. It's the default animation.

Comment: Are you scrolling any where in your code ?

Comment: Through the protocol, I am sending the cells over, since I need the indexPath. Then I am choosing the first index path (function tapped) which is returned, that gives me which one the user has tapped.

Comment: @user1046037 Not in my code, no. But my tableView is scrolling enabled as default.

Comment: In your function `tapped(cell:)` then way you create `indexPath` seems to be wrong. Couple of mistakes here. You are hard coding row as zero.

Comment: @user1046037 Yeah thanks for that, I did that. Great suggestion, however it doesn't resolve the two issues which I have.

Comment: You have convert the frame rect to the view’s frame text. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763360/how-to-get-center-point-of-cell?rq=1

Comment: @user1046037 tableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.center)  was actually not an appropriate method to use here, hence replaced it with simply, tableView.indexPath(for: <Cell>). Your suggestion wouldn't be relevant in this context I think. Tx nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UISegmentedControl` are reusing [Default behaviour of UITableView].

To avoid that, keep `dictionary` for getting and storing values.

Another thing, try `outlet connection as Action` for `UISegmentedControl` in `UIViewController` itself, instead of your `UITableViewCell`

The below code will not reload your tableview when you tap `UISegmentedControl` . You can avoid, delegates call too.

Below codes are basic demo for `UISegmentedControl`. Do customise as per your need.

```
var segmentDict = [Int : Int]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0...29 // number of rows count
    {
        segmentDict[i] = 0 //DEFAULT SELECTED SEGMENTS
    }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SOTableViewCell

    cell.mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentDict[indexPath.row]!

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

@IBAction func mySegmentAcn(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let cellPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tblVw)
    let indPath = tblVw.indexPathForRow(at: cellPosition)

    segmentDict[(indPath?.row)!] = sender.selectedSegmentIndex


    print("Sender.tag     ", indPath)

}
```

Comment: Can u give up vote  too? It will useful for SO followers?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `indexPathForRow(at: <#T##CGPoint#>)` function to get the indexPath object of cell you can directly use `indexPath(for: <#T##UITableViewCell#>)` as you are receiving the cell object to `func tapped(cell: MetricsViewCell) {}` and try to update your data on the UI always in main thready as below.

```
func tapped(cell: MetricsViewCell) {
    if let lIndexPath = table.indexPath(for: <#T##UITableViewCell#>){
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            table.reloadRows(at: lIndexPath, with: .none)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using viewContext of my app delegate's container, to update data. viewContext runs on main thread, hence that's not a problem. Still I tried explicit main thread, doesn't work :(

Comment: @Manganese what about to get the indexpath object of a cell? Have tried it?

Comment: Yep, that was the same suggestion as by @user1046037 :

    func tapped(cell: MetricsViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            }
        }
    }