# stepper increase value of label, then multiplied by value inside of init function from array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

my table view cell

```
class Service1TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var quantityStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var Service1image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pricingInfo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepperLabel: UILabel!



func setService1(Dry: Service1){
    Service1image.image = Dry.service1image
    pricingInfo.tag = Dry.service1Pricing
    serviceTitle.text = Dry.service1Title
}
//save data from each cell and multiply for total service


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Method .valueChanged activated")

    //Update stepperlabel
    stepperLabel.text = String(Int(quantityStepper.value))

}
}
```

ViewController

```
class Service1ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var service1TableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var service1Total: UILabel!


var Dry: [Service1] = []

var step = [Stepper]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Dry = Options()



}
func Options() -> [Service1]{

    var dryOptions: [Service1] = []

    let option1 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option2 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option3 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option4 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option5 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option6 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option7 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option8 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option9 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option10 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option11 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option12 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option13 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option14 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option15 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option16 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option17 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option18 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option19 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option20 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option21 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option22 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option23 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option24 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option25 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option26 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option27 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option28 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option29 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option30 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
    let option31 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))

    dryOptions.append(option1)
    dryOptions.append(option2)
    dryOptions.append(option3)
    dryOptions.append(option4)
    dryOptions.append(option5)
    dryOptions.append(option6)
    dryOptions.append(option7)
    dryOptions.append(option8)
    dryOptions.append(option9)
    dryOptions.append(option10)
    dryOptions.append(option11)
    dryOptions.append(option12)
    dryOptions.append(option13)
    dryOptions.append(option14)
    dryOptions.append(option15)
    dryOptions.append(option16)
    dryOptions.append(option17)
    dryOptions.append(option18)
    dryOptions.append(option19)
    dryOptions.append(option20)
    dryOptions.append(option21)
    dryOptions.append(option22)
    dryOptions.append(option23)
    dryOptions.append(option24)
    dryOptions.append(option25)
    dryOptions.append(option26)
    dryOptions.append(option27)
    dryOptions.append(option28)
    dryOptions.append(option29)
    dryOptions.append(option30)
    dryOptions.append(option31)

    return dryOptions

}

}
extension Service1ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return Dry.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Dry1 = Dry[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Service1Cell") as! Service1TableViewCell
    cell.setService1(Dry: Dry1)
    cell.stepper = step[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

// send selected data to cart
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


}


}
```

(cart tableView) service choice cell

```
class CartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoiceImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoiceTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoiceAmount:UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var serviceChoicePrice: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

(cart tableView) order total cell

```
class CartTotalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var orderTotal: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var OrderTax: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var deliveryFee: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var grandTotal: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

How do I program the stepper to increase the label in value when selected above is the current code I am using but it crashes upon clicking the stepper, also how do I take this value and either send it to the cart vc to multiply with pricing info in the Options array and send the selected items data to the service choice cell in the cart, or multiply it in the Service1ViewController and send the total data to the cart along with sending the selected items data to the service choice cell?

Comment: R u using storyboard ?

Comment: yes the init function is a sniper from another class If you would like me to post all of the code I would be happy to do so

Comment: Stepper is in UITableViewCell. Each cell, u have to increase/decrease ur order. Right ?

Comment: yes its in the swift document for the tableviewcell

Comment: I have update UIStepper basic answer. U can chk it. With this, u can customise as per your need.

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' I get this error from inputing tableView.reloadData() in the action function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did sample for Add to Cart screen. User may increase/ decrease their order. Initially, you have to store default values in `dictionary`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636176/uitableview-reloadrowsat-takes-two-hits-for-table-to-be-updated-and-scroll-e/48639466#48639466) link is for `UISegmentedControl`.

In `Storyboard` itself, set `UIStepper's` `minimumValue`, `maximumValue` and `Step`

```
var orderCount = [Int : Int]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0...29  // TotaL number of rows
    {
       orderCount[i] = 1 // DEFAULT order count will be 1
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SOTableViewCell
    cell.myStepper.tag = indexPath.row // ADDING TAG
    cell.testLbl.text = String(orderCount[indexPath.row]!) // PASS VALUES TO LABEL
    cell.myStepper.value = Double(orderCount[indexPath.row]!) // PASS VALUES TO STEPPER
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}


//ACTION should be in this ViewController. 
@IBAction func stepperAcn(_ sender: UIStepper) {

    print("sender.value         ", sender.value)
    let getTag : Int = sender.tag

    orderCount[getTag] = Int(sender.value)

    tblVw.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: confusing I need to explain more

Comment: Action for UIStepper should be in UIViewController. Instead of **cell.quantityStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setter: cell.stepperLabel.text), for: .valueChanged) **

Comment: I revised the post to make my question understandable, I appreciate your fast response but not everything you posted pertains to my entire question

Comment: 1.  cell.stepper = step[indexPath.row].  what is this ? 2.  @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Method .valueChanged activated")

    //Update stepperlabel
    stepperLabel.text = String(Int(quantityStepper.value))

} Do this action in UIViewController, not in UITableViewCell

Comment: ok I understand I have to perform that action in the UIViewController, but about the rest of the question such as multiplying that value by the pricing integer (thats also another issue should I use double to display decimals) and moving the data to the cartVC

Comment: Price 5.29rs. If user increase by 1, It should display 10.58 ?? am I right ?

Comment: no the stepperLabel displays an integer which I would like to take the per specific cell and multiply it by the pricing value for that specific cell (this is done for all cells) then display the total in service1Total UILabel and forward the data of the cells with a stepperLabel value above 0 to the cart in ( service choice cell) and the service1Total to the (order total cell)

Comment: Can u post ur Screen design ?

Comment: can I send it to you privately?

Comment: Ok. Give ur mail id

Comment: buildyoursoftware@icloud.com

Comment: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' I get this error from inputing tableView.reloadData()