# How to cast view TableViewCell to UIGestureView

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to change the my table view cell contents on gesture view tap, However I am getting the error

**Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

Could not cast value of type 'UILabel' (0x117f4ad68) to 'MyApplication.Read'

```
func ReadAnswer(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)  {
    let CellIndex = sender.view?.tag
    print(CellIndex!)
    let test = sender.view as! Read!  // This produces error

    test?.comment.text = "You have clicked on cell \(CellIndex)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let mycell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Read", for: indexPath) as! Read

    mycell.comment.tag = indexPath.row
    mycell.comment.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]

    let Gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ReadAnswer(_:)))
    Gesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

    mycell.comment.addGestureRecognizer(Gesture)

    return cell
}
```

Again on Label click I want to change the content of that label to say you have clicked on cell (CellIndex) . I can get the correct index on every click however on the **Let Test** it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are added `Gesture` to `UILabel`..!! `comment` is `UILabel`.

```
let Gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ReadAnswer(_:)))
Gesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

mycell.comment.addGestureRecognizer(Gesture)
```

In `Gesture Action`, sender.view should be UILabel. So that following error occured.

Could not cast value of type 'UILabel' (0x117f4ad68) to 'MyApplication.Read'

```
func ReadAnswer(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)  {
    let CellIndex = sender.view?.tag
    print(CellIndex!)


    let test = sender.view as! Read!  // This produces error

    test?.comment.text = "You have clicked on cell \(CellIndex)"

}
```

**To Solve**

We have to use, dictionary for this . So, we can avoid tableView reuse.  You can get my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655497/stepper-increase-value-of-label-then-multiplied-by-value-inside-of-init-functio/48657267#48657267) for UIStepper. Same logic as follows.

```
var textDict = [Int : String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<70 // numberOfRows
    {
        textDict[i] = "Hello"
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 70
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "table", for: indexPath) as! TblTableViewCell

    let Gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ReadAnswer))
    Gesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

    cell.commentLbl.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.commentLbl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.commentLbl.addGestureRecognizer(Gesture)

    cell.commentLbl.text = textDict[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 50
}

@objc func ReadAnswer(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)  {

    let CellIndex : Int = (sender.view?.tag)!

    textDict[CellIndex] = "You have clicked on cell \(CellIndex)"

    tblView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some background points: Don't add a gesture recognizer every time you add a cell. As your cells are recycled you will wind up with more and more gesture recognizers. Add a flag to your custom cell class that tells if you've already added your gesture recognizer, and only add one if you haven't done that already.

(Won't prevent your code from working, but still important ). Method names and variable names in Swift should start with a lower case letter. Class and type names should start with upper-case letters.

As to why your force cast fails, it sounds like the `mycell.comment` outlet of your cell is not of the desired type `Read`. Based on the error, it's of type `UILabel`, not `Read` (whatever that is.) You haven't given us enough information to help with that part however. You need to explain how you've set up your my class's outlets, and also explain what the `Read` type is.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ReadAnswer` function, `sender` has a reference to the view to which it is attached. That view is the `UILabel` you named `comment`.

Change your function as follows:

```
func ReadAnswer(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)  {
    let CellIndex = sender.view?.tag
    print(CellIndex!)
    if let test = sender.view as? UILabel {

        test.comment.text = "You have clicked on cell \(CellIndex)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is Tested Answer that I just wrote

**My array**

```
var staticArrayy = ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]
```

**my tableview Delegate**

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return staticArrayy.count
    }

    //Setting cells data
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = self.myDemoTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        ///Adding Gesture
        let Gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableViewVC.ReadAnswer(_:)))
        Gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        Gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        Gesture.delegate = self
        cell.comment.addGestureRecognizer(Gesture)

        cell.comment.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        ///Assuming mycell.comment.text is a Label Connected
        cell.comment.text = staticArrayy[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

//Setting height of cells
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{        
    return 60
}
```

**TapGesture Handler**

```
@objc func ReadAnswer(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        //Get position in View
        let myPosition = sender.location(in: self.myDemoTableView)

        //Get current Index Path
        let indexPath : IndexPath = self.myDemoTableView.indexPathForRow(at: myPosition)!

        //Time to Show Answer
        var cell = self.myDemoTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell = self.myDemoTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.comment.text = "You have clicked on cell \(indexPath.row)"

        //Re-Deque issue
        //Update the Array Content at same Index whose value is changed
        self.staticArrayy[indexPath.row] = cell.comment.text!
    }
```

**My cell CLass**

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var comment: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Output :

When tableView loads For first time

[image]

When TableView Cells are clicked

[image]

Comment: Can u add more than 30 cells and check? Whether is it reusing of not ?

Comment: Likewise , can you explain more please , I can add upto 30 rows what next to do ?

Comment: Click, row no 1, to change label text and then scroll to bottom, do see any diff ?

Comment: Okay I got Re-Deque Issue , Solved Check Updated Answer, Thanks for the info , I missed doing that for example

Comment: Now, pls check my answer. Both are identical,

Comment: Yes I agree, I am thankful to you that you did noticed the mistake in my answer, just some minor difference  , I am using just an Array , Not maintaining a Dictionary , my way of accessing cell and updating content is Different from your answer , So you can't say I copied your answer , thanks  @McDonal_11

Comment: I am not saying that Copying. Just I said.